# Batch copy and rename files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to copy some directories from the network to my machine and remove the extension `.nary` from the files in the copied folders; so a file `myFile.doc.nary` will become `myFile.doc`. I've got the following Windows batch file, but don't know how to limit the rename to the two folders if the batch file is run from `c:\`:

```
xcopy /s \\some_server\MYFOLDER1 c:\MYFOLDER1\
xcopy /s \\some_server\MYFOLDER2 c:\MYFOLDER2\

for /r %%x in (*.nary) do (
    ren "%%x" *.
    )
pause
```

How do you limit the rename to those two folders on `c:\`? Also, is it possible to not run the copies if the folders are already on my machine's `c:\`? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How do you limit the rename to those two folders on `c:\`?

Just use `for /d` to loop through the directories.

Modified batch file:

```
@echo off
xcopy /s \\some_server\MYFOLDER1 c:\MYFOLDER1\
xcopy /s \\some_server\MYFOLDER2 c:\MYFOLDER2\
for /d %%x in (C:\MYFOLDER1 c:\MYFOLDER2) do (
  ren "%%x\*.nary" *.
  )
pause
```

---

#### Also, is it possible to not run the copies if the folders are already in `c:\?`

Test if the folder already exists before running the `xcopy`:

Modified batch file:

```
@echo off
if not exist C:\MYFOLDER1 echo xcopy /s \\some_server\MYFOLDER1 c:\MYFOLDER1\
if not exist C:\MYFOLDER2 echo xcopy /s \\some_server\MYFOLDER2 c:\MYFOLDER2\
for /d %%x in (C:\MYFOLDER1 c:\MYFOLDER2) do (
  ren "%%x\*.nary" *.
  )
pause
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /d](http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) - Conditionally perform a command on several Directories/Folders.
- [if](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) - Conditionally perform a command.
- [ren](http://ss64.com/nt/ren.html) - Rename a file or files.
- [xcopy](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) - Copy files and/or directory trees to another folder.